# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - liferay

Tags: mysql, liferay

I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:144)
... 192 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`audit_compliance`.`audit_compliance_auditdetailes`, CONSTRAINT `auditComplianceCompanyId` FOREIGN KEY (`auditComplianceCompanyId`) REFERENCES `audit_compliance_auditcompliancecompany` (`audit)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1135)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
```

I am using liferay 6.2. It has no mapping key in service builder, so I manually gave the reference in my database table.
The referencing is correct, I dont understand the reason it is giving error.

```
ALTER TABLE `audit_compliance`.`audit_compliance_auditdetailes` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `documentCollectionIds`;
ALTER TABLE `audit_compliance`.`audit_compliance_auditdetailes` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `documentCollectionIds`
FOREIGN KEY (`documentCollectionIds`)
REFERENCES `audit_compliance`.`audit_compliance_documentcollection` (`name`);
```

Answer (score 0):

As ServiceBuilder doesn't include foreign key references, it might use the wrong order to insert data into tables: Now you enforce the foreign key relationship, but ServiceBuilder still doesn't know about it.

Decide if you use ServiceBuilder's persistence (then you might want to go without foreign keys) or roll your own. You can still use ServiceBuilder for the service layer and just use your own persistence in the background.